# GRAPH: find an algorithm to determine the shortest path from one point to another in a rectangular maze?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I'm getting such an headache trying to elaborate an appropriate algorithm to go from a **START** position to a **EXIT** position in a maze. 
For what is worth, the maze is **rectangular**, **maxsize 500x500** and, in theory, is resolvable by DFS with some branch and bound techniques ...

```
10 3 4  
7 6  
3  3  1  2  2  1  0  
2  2  2  4  2  2  5  
2  2  1  3  0  2  2  
2  2  1  3  3  4  2  
3  4  4  3  1  1  3  
1  2  2  4  2  2  1 

Output:
5 1 4 2
```

Explanation:
Our agent looses energy every time he gives a step and he can only move UP, DOWN, LEFT and RIGHT. Also, if the agent arrives with a remaining energy of zero or less, he dies, so we print something like "Impossible".

So, in the input **10** is the initial agent's energy, **3 4** is the **START** position (i.e. column 3, line 4) and we have a maze **7x6**. Think this as a kind of labyrinth, in which I want to find the exit that gives the agent a better remaining energy (shortest path).

In case there are paths which lead to the same remaining energy, we choose the one which has the small number of steps, of course.

I need to know if a DFS to a maze 500x500 in the worst case is feasible with these limitations and how to do it, storing the remaining energy in each step and the number of steps taken so far.

The output means the agent arrived with remaining energy= 5 to the exit pos 1 4 in 2 steps. If we look carefully, in this maze it's also possible to exit at pos 3 1 (column 3, row 1) with the same energy but with 3 steps, so we choose the better one.

With these in mind, can someone help me some code or pseudo-code?
I have troubles working this around with a 2D array and how to store the remaining energy, the path (or number of steps taken)....

EDIT:

Larry, as I said, I'me a little bit confused about the code. Here's what I've tried so far, only to determine the shortest path with less steps from START to EXIT, fixing EXIT in the meanwhile...

```
public class exitFromMaze {

    int energy, startY, startX, xMax, yMax;
    int adjMatrix[][];
    boolean visited[][];
    ArrayList<Cell> neighbours;

    //ArrayList<Cell> visited;
    Cell start;
    Stack<Cell> stack;

    public exM() {
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nrTests = cin.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < nrTests; i++) {
            energy = cin.nextInt();
            startY = cin.nextInt()-1; //start at columnstartY
            startX = cin.nextInt()-1; //start at line startX
            xMax = cin.nextInt();//7 cols
            yMax = cin.nextInt(); //8 rows

            adjMatrix = new int[yMax][xMax];
            visited = new boolean[yMax][xMax];
            //visited = new ArrayList<Cell>();
            this.stack = new Stack<Cell>();
            for (int r = 0; r < yMax; r++) { // yMax linhas
                for (int c = 0; c < xMax; c++) { // xMax colunas
                    adjMatrix[r][c] = cin.nextInt();
                    visited[r][c] = false;
                    //System.out.println("matrix["+r+"]["+c+"] = "+adjMatrix[r][c]);
                }
            }
            start= new Cell(startX, startY, 0);
            //adiciona a pos actual à pilha de celulas/nos
            stack.push(start);
            //printArray(yMax, xMax);
            findBestExit();
        }//end_of_test_Cases
    }

    private void findBestExit() {
        // BEGINNING OF DEPTH-FIRST SEARCH
        Cell curCell;

        while (!(stack.empty())) {
            curCell = (Cell) (stack.pop());
            //just fix an exit point ...for now (if it works for one, it has to work for all the other possible exits)
            if (curCell.row==0 && curCell.col== 4) {
                System.out.println("Arrived at pos: "+curCell.row+","+curCell.col+" with E= "+(energy-curCell.getEnergy())+" with "+curCell.getSteps()+" steps");
                //finish = curCell;
                break;
            } else {
                visited[curCell.row][curCell.col] = true;
            }
            this.neighbours = (ArrayList<Cell>) curCell.getNeighbours(this.xMax, this.yMax);
            for (Cell neighbourCell: neighbours) {
                //1- I think something's missing here and it would be here the point to cut some cases...isn't it?
              if ( curCell.getEnergy() + neighbourCell.getEnergy() < this.energy && !visited[neighbourCell.row][neighbourCell.col]){
                  neighbourCell.energy+= curCell.energy;
                  neighbourCell.setSteps(curCell.getSteps()+1);
                  neighbourCell.setPrevious(curCell);
                  stack.push(neighbourCell);
              }
              // ...
            }
        }
        // END OF DEPTH-FIRST SEARCH and DIJKSTRA?
    }

    class Cell {

        int row;
        int col;
        int energy;
        int steps;
        Cell previous;
        //Node next;

        public Cell(int x, int y, int steps) {
            this.row = x;
            this.col = y;
            this.energy = adjMatrix[x][y];
            this.steps = steps;
            //this.next = null;
            this.previous = null;
        }

        public Cell(int x, int y, Cell prev) {
            this.row = x;
            this.col = y;
            this.steps = 0;
            this.energy = adjMatrix[x][y];
            this.previous = prev;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "(,"+this.getRow()+","+this.getCol()+")";
        }



        public int getEnergy() {
            return energy;
        }

        public void setEnergy(int energy) {
            this.energy = energy;
        }

        public Cell getPrevious() {
            return previous;
        }

        public void setPrevious(Cell previous) {
            this.previous = previous;
        }

        public int getRow() {
            return row;
        }

        public void setRow(int x) {
            this.row = x;
        }

        public int getCol() {
            return col;
        }

        public void setCol(int y) {
            this.col = y;
        }

        public int getSteps() {
            return steps;
        }

        public void setSteps(int steps) {
            this.steps = steps;
        }

        public Cell south(int verticalLimit) {
            Cell ret = null;
            if (row < (verticalLimit - 1)) {
                ret = new Cell(row+1, col, this);
                //ret.previous = this;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        /**
         * Gives the north to our current Cell
         * @return the Cell in that direction, null if it's impossible
         * to go in that direction
         */
        public Cell north() {
            Cell ret = null;
            if (row > 0) {
                ret = new Cell(row-1, col ,this);
                //ret.previous = this;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        /**
         * Gives the west (left) to our current Cell
         * @return the Cell in that direction, null if it's
         * impossible to go in that direction
         */
        public Cell west() {
            Cell ret = null;
            if (col > 0) {
                ret = new Cell(row, col-1,this);
                //ret.previous = this;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        /**
         * Gives the east direction(right) to our current Cell
         * @return the Cell in that direction, null if it's
         * impossible to go in that direction
         */
        public Cell east(int horizontalLimit) {
            Cell ret = null;
            //if it's inside the number max of collumns
            if (col < (horizontalLimit - 1)) {
                ret = new Cell(row , col+1, this);
            }
            return ret;
        }

        public List getNeighbours(int xlimit, int ylimit) {
            ArrayList<Cell> res = new ArrayList<Cell>(4);
            Cell n;
            n = south(ylimit);
            if (n != null) {
                res.add(n);
            }
            n = north();
            if (n != null) {
                res.add(n);
            }
            n = east(xlimit);
            if (n != null) {
                res.add(n);
            }
            n = west();
            if (n != null) {
                res.add(n);
            }
            return res;
        }
    }

    private void printArray(int h, int w) {
        int i, j;
        // print array in rectangular form
        System.out.print("   ");
        for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
            System.out.print("\t" + i);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int r = 0; r < h; r++) {
            System.out.print("  " + r);
            for (int c = 0; c < w; c++) {
                System.out.print("\t" + adjMatrix[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new exM();
    }
}
```

For the input:

```
1  
40 3 3  
7 8  
12 11 12 11  3 12 12  
12 11 11 12  2  1 13  
11 11 12  2 13  2 14  
10 11 13  3  2  1 12  
10 11 13 13 11 12 13 
12 12 11 13 11 13 12  
13 12 12 11 11 11 11  
13 13 10 10 13 11 12
```

It should print:

```
12 5 1 8
```

i.e., the agent exit in a better exit, (0,4),with the a remaining energy= 12 and in only 8 steps.

With my ideas, your help, is it ask to much to point me out my fails or correct them?
I'm getting so sick of this ... because I gotta be complicating something easy...

More inputs/outputs (when it's not possible to achieve an exit alive (with Energy>0), just print that fact).

```
3 
40 3 3 
7 8  
12 11 12 11  3 12 12 
12 11 11 12  2  1 13  
11 11 12  2 13  2 14 
10 11 13  3  2  1 12 
10 11 13 13 11 12 13  
12 12 11 13 11 13 12  
13 12 12 11 11 11 11 
13 13 10 10 13 11 12 
8 3 4 
7 6 
4  3  3  2  2  3  2  
2  5  2  2  2  3  3  
2  1  2  2  3  2  2  
4  3  3  2  2  4  1  
3  1  4  3  2  3  1  
2  2  3  3  0  3  4  
10 3 4  
7 6  
3  3  1  2  2  1  0  
2  2  2  4  2  2  5  
2  2  1  3  0  2  2 
2  2  1  3  3  4  2  
3  4  4  3  1  1  3  
1  2  2  4  2  2  1  

Output 
12 5 1 8  
Goodbye cruel world!
5 1 4 2
```

Comment: Using a regular DFS, you might need to visit some points more than once -- imagine something like 1 1 1, 100 100 1, 1 1 1, where you would ideally go around the 100's, but you might go down twice and get an suboptimal answer in terms of energy.

Answer (score 8):

Just use [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm), using the implicit graph in the cardinal directions.  Using the heap implementation it will be `O(V log V)`, which should be good enough for `500x500`.  The first time you relax a node, it is with the lowest energy used you can get there.  You can set up a node's precessor fairly trivially with this algorithm.

Edit:  some pseudo code with explanation for Dijkstra's algorithm:

```
function Dijkstra( graph, source ):
     // distance is infinity to everywhere initially
     dist = initialize list of size V to infinity 
     // no vertices pointed to anything
     previous = initialize list of size V to undefined

     // distance from source to source is 0
     dist[source] = 0

     Q = priority queue

     insert all vertices into Q

     while Q is not empty:
         // get the vertex closest to the source
         current_vertex = Q.pop

         if dist[current_vertex] == infinity
             break

         // these are the adjacent vertices in the four cardinal direction
         for each vertex next to current_vertex:
              // if it costs less energy to go to vertex
              //   from current_vertex
              if ( dist[current_vertex] + energy[vertex] < dist[vertex] )
                  dist[vertex] = dist[current_vertex] + energy[vertex]
                  previous[vertex] = current_vertex

              // Another if statement here to 
              //   minimize steps if energy is the same

     // Now after this is done, you should have the cheapest cost to 
     //   each vertex in "dist".  Take the cheapest one on the edge.

     // You can walk backwards on the "previous" to reconstruct the path taken.
```

That's the general pseudo code, though you would also have to keep track of the number of steps, mostly as a tiebreaker, so it shouldn't be too much more work.

As for the DFS solution, it depends on what the energy can be.  If it is bounded, small, and an int, you can convert the 2D graph into a 3D graph on `x-y-e`, where `e` is the energy remaining - you start at the initial energy, and work your way down, but keeping track of places you've been before.

Edit:  For the DFS solution, it should be `O(H*W*E)`, for E <= 30000, H, W <= 500 it will not likely be fast enough, at least for real time, and might take a bit of memory.

Comment: How can I do that with cardinal directions?I don't know where to limit, etc. I just need a little push, the problem for me is always putting the idea to code, specially when I tried a lot.
Tks anyway!

Comment: I'll re-edit with some sample pseudo-code, but this assumes you are already familiar with Dijkstra's algorithm, at least somewhat.  Check out the Wikipedia link.

Comment: Yes I am, with the simple Dijkstra, Floyd-Warshall, DFS and BFS ... and then I'll study Bellman-Ford, bipartite matching, min-cut max flow.
I just want to be able to do/see, at least, how to implement these ideas, with each algorithm.
Tks and please excuse my english, but it's 4:28 AM ...can't blame me! eheheh bad habbits :$

Comment: The energy it's, indeed, an int. The constraints limits are:
0 < E ≤ 30000 the suit's starting energy  
0 ≤ W ≤ 500 the rectangle's width  
0 ≤ H ≤ 500 rectangle's height  
0 < X < W the starting X position  
0 < Y < H the starting Y position  
0 ≤ D ≤ 10000 the energy lost in each sector

Comment: I abstracted a little bit away from your problem, though I added some stuff on the comments.  Let me know if you want something more specific.

Comment: Thank you Larry.I will see this and think about it in a few hours from now. If I implement this in Java, C/C++ I'll let you know if it passed our university contest platform. (hope it doesn't get me a TLE ...because I don't know the limit time, but it's typically 1sec)

Comment: Larry, if it isn't asking too much, I would really apprecciate your help it the JAVA code I've just edited above.
Thanks once again for your patient!

Answer (score 4):

A* is the way, if you are scared about efficiency: check it out [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). Or if you feel brave you can go for D* [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D*_search_algorithm).. both will be more efficient (because they use an heuristic to estimate the distance) but not so hard to implement!

BFS is definetely not a good way to implement pathfinding, it's just simple..

Comment: In fact, this exercise is from a programming contest and I know it's not supposed to use heuristic search yet...,althought it's possible.
A* and IDA* I know them because I studied in Artificial Inteligence, but, again, my problem is the code, not the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one implementation that encodes your map with directions you must move to to get to the exit. It find the shortest path from any accessible point within the entire map:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Maze {

  private static final char E = 'E';   // Ending position
  private static final char X = 'X';   // Wall
  private static final char O = ' ';   // Space
  private static final char L = 'L';   // Left
  private static final char R = 'R';   // Right
  private static final char U = 'U';   // Up
  private static final char D = 'D';   // Down

  private static final char FALSE = '0';   // Not accessible
  private static final char TRUE = '1';    // Is accessible
  private static final Node END_NODE = new Node(4, 4);

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[][] maze = new char[][] { 
      {X, X, X, X, X, X},
      {X, O, O, X, O, X},
      {X, O, X, X, O, X},
      {X, O, O, O, X, X},
      {X, X, O, X, O, X},
      {X, O, O, O, O, X},
      {X, O, X, X, O, X},
      {X, X, X, X, X, X}};

    // PLOT THE DESTINATION CELL AND ADD IT TO LIST
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    nodes.add(END_NODE);
    maze[END_NODE.row][END_NODE.col] = E;

    // PRINT THE MAZE BEFORE ANY CALCULATIONS
    printMaze(maze);

    // SOLVE THE MAZE
    fillMaze(maze, nodes);
    printMaze(maze);

    // CONVERT MAZE TO AN ADJACENCY MATRIX
    compileMaze(maze);
    printMaze(maze);
  }

  /**
   * The parallel arrays define all four directions radiating from
   * the dequeued node's location. 
   * 
   * Each node will have up to four neighboring cells; some of these
   * cells are accessible, some are not. 
   * 
   * If a neighboring cell is accessible, we encode it with a directional
   * code that calculates the direction we must take should we want to 
   * navigate to the dequeued node's location from this neighboring cell.
   * 
   * Once encoded into our maze, this neighboring cell is itself queued 
   * up as a node so that recursively, we can encode the entire maze.
   */
  public static final void fillMaze(char[][] maze, List<Node> nodes) {
    int[] rowDirections = {-1, 1,  0, 0};  
    int[] colDirections = { 0, 0, -1, 1};

    // dequeue our first node
    Node destination = nodes.get(0);
    nodes.remove(destination);

    // examine all four neighboring cells for this dequeued node
    for(int index = 0; index < rowDirections.length; index++) {
      int rowIndex = destination.row + rowDirections[index];
      int colIndex = destination.col + colDirections[index];

      // if this neighboring cell is accessible, encode it and add it
      // to the queue
      if(maze[rowIndex][colIndex] == O) {
        maze[rowIndex][colIndex] = getOppositeDirection(rowDirections[index], colDirections[index]);
        nodes.add(new Node(rowIndex, colIndex));
      }
    }
    // if our queue is not empty, call this method again recursively 
    // so we can fill entire maze with directional codes
    if(nodes.size() > 0) {
      fillMaze(maze, nodes);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Converts the maze to an adjacency matrix. 
   */
  private static void compileMaze(char[][] maze) {
    for(int r = 0; r < maze.length; r++) {
      for(int c = 0; c < maze[0].length; c++) {
        if(maze[r][c] == X || maze[r][c] == O) {
          maze[r][c] = FALSE;
        }
        else {
          maze[r][c] = TRUE;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * prints the specified two dimensional array 
   */
  private static final void printMaze(char[][] maze) {
    System.out.println("====================================");
    for(int r = 0; r < maze.length; r++) {
      for(int c = 0; c < maze[0].length; c++) {
        System.out.print(maze[r][c] + "  ");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("====================================");
  }

  /**
   * Simply returns the opposite direction from those specified 
   * by our parallel direction arrays in method fillMaze. 
   * 
   * coordinate 1, 1 is the center of the char[][] array and 
   * applying the specified row and col offsets, we return the
   * correct code (opposite direction)
   */
  private static char getOppositeDirection(int row, int col) {
    char[][] opposites = new char[][] {{O, D, O},{R, O, L},{O, U, O}};
     return opposites[1 + row][1 + col];
  }
}

class Node {
  int row;
  int col;

  public Node(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
    row = rowIndex;
    col = colIndex;
  }
}
```

Here is the output from this small program

```
====================================
X  X  X  X  X  X  
X        X     X  
X     X  X     X  
X           X  X  
X  X     X  E  X  
X              X  
X     X  X     X  
X  X  X  X  X  X  
====================================
====================================
X  X  X  X  X  X  
X  D  L  X     X  
X  D  X  X     X  
X  R  D  L  X  X  
X  X  D  X  E  X  
X  R  R  R  U  X  
X  U  X  X  U  X  
X  X  X  X  X  X  
====================================
====================================
0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  1  1  0  0  0  
0  1  0  0  0  0  
0  1  1  1  0  0  
0  0  1  0  1  0  
0  1  1  1  1  0  
0  1  0  0  1  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  
====================================
```