# Can you please provide some pseudo code to display the path of a maze?

Tags: java

I am trying to write an algoritim to find and display the path in a maze.

The maze outline is read from an input file and stored in a 2D array.

I need to start the maze at point (1,1) and find any path through the maze.

I have a findpath()  method which I am able to find the exit with what i have written but after finding the exit I need to display the path i took to get there by popping the stack(this I am currently unable to do and is what I need assistance with). Upon finding the goal the stack should be popped to completion and will contain only the path taken to find the goal. (at this point i will just change the value inside those rooms but i know how to do that)

Please review where my pushes are occurring and provide some guidance as to what order things should be pushed and popped off so that the above criteria is met.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

here is the current output: The o was originally an empty space but when detected as goal it was changed

```
********************
*     *            *
** ** ***** ** *****
*  *  *      * *   *
*  *    *    * * * *
*       *        * *
*************  **  *
*                  O
********************
```

---

Code:

```
 public void findPath() {  
    Room start = rooms[1][1];
    push(start);
    while(!isEmpty()) { 
        current = pop();
        System.out.println("The value stored in current is" + current.getValue()+ "");
        if (current == null) 
            System.out.println("current is null");
        //This is finding the goal the walls will contain a * 
        else if(current.getValue() == ' ' && current.getRight() == null || current.getValue() == ' ' && current.getLeft() == null || current.getValue() == ' ' && current.getUp() == null || current.getValue() == ' ' && current.getRight() == null){
            current.setValue('O');
            for(int i = 0; i < tos; i++ ){
                pop();
            }

        System.out.println(" I found the end here is the path:" + current.getPrevious().getValue()+ " jjj");
        } else if(current.getBlocked() == false && current.getVisited() == false) {
            System.out.println("pushing currents neighbors left, right....etc" +  "current is at" + current.getCord());
            current.setVisited(true);
            if(current.getRight() != null){
                current.getRight().setPrevious(current);
                push(current.getRight());
                System.out.println("Inside push 1" +current.getRight().getCord());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Inside push right is null");
            }
            if(current.getLeft() != null) {
                current.getLeft().setPrevious(current);
                push(current.getLeft());
                System.out.println("Inside push 2 " + current.getLeft().getCord());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Inside push left is null");
            }
            if(current.getUp() != null)  {
                current.getUp().setPrevious(current);
                push(current.getUp());
                System.out.println("Inside push 3" + current.getUp().getCord());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Inside push up is null");
            }
            if(current.getDown() != null) {
                current.getDown().setPrevious(current);
                push(current.getDown());
                System.out.println("inside push 4" + current.getDown().getCord());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Inside push down is null");
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < rows ; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns ; j++) {
            System.out.print(rooms[i][j].getValue());
        }   
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: One method is to follow the right wall until the end is found, I think this works for most mazes, otherwise, a pathfinding algorithm like A*, or D* Lite should help you. There are many implementations that you can study.

Comment: what is the current output of this code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GRAPH PROBLEM: find an algorithm to determine the shortest path from one point to another in a rectangular maze?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634647/graph-problem-find-an-algorithm-to-determine-the-shortest-path-from-one-point-t)

Comment: It is not a shortest path problem i just need to figure out in which order to push and pop my values so that when the goal is found the only values on the stack are a correct path to the goal..

Comment: here is the current output: ********************
*     *            *
** ** ***** ** *****
*  *  *      * *   *
*  *    *    * * * *
*       *        * *
*************  **  *
*                  O
********************

Comment: sorry didn't paste right. The output was added to my question. Please help. Any assitance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you want extra credit from your professor for printing out the path, and you get help from here, be sure to let him know, and credit your source.  Only reason I say this:  This assignment looks *really* familiar.

Comment: ok. to display the path you should print different symbol. isn't it? or what you mean by "display the path" ? i don't see any such symbol in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not pseudocode, but a talking point:

Consider how you traversed through the maze.  If you leave "breadcrumbs" throughout, as you were working with the optimal path, you will have labeled your optimal path.